# PHP Replace words in other file

Tags: php, replace

i have got a variable with the value of:
**1a2b3c**.
Now I want to find the "1" in the other file ("test.css") and replace it with "a". Then I want to replace the "2" with the "b" and the "3" with the "c" How can I do this? Is it possible? Thank you for your help. And sorry I didnt say that before but I dont want to replace it in the same file. I want to create a new file with these replaced values.

Code:

```
$arr1 = str_split($name);
$arr2 = str_split($_GET[$name]);
```

Then I got two arrays:

1:

```
[0]=1
[0]=2
[0]=3
```

2:

```
[0]=a
[0]=b
[0]=c
```

PS: There are not exactly 3 values every time. Sometimes it looks like: **1a2b3c4d5e...** I want to do that dynamicly

PPS: Sorry for my bad english...ˆˆ

So heres ALL my code:

index.php

```
<?php
include 'parser.php';

print "<form method=\"get\" action=\"test.php\">";
$parser = new ConfigParser("test.theme");
$parser->parse();
print "<input type=\"submit\"></input>";
print "</form>";

?>
```

parser.php

```
<?php

class ConfigParser 
{

    private $name = "";

    function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->name = $filename;
    }

    function parse() {

        foreach(file($this->name) as $line) {
            if(strlen($line) < 3){

                echo ("YOU ARE TO DAMM STUPID TO MAKE A CONFIG FILE, IDIOT!");
                return;

         }
            list($name, $type, $label) = explode(":", $line);


        print "<p>". $label. "</p><input type=\"" . $type . "\" name=\"". $name. "\"> </input>";
        }
        print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"theme\" value=\"" .$this->name ."\" readonly></input>";
    }

}


?>
```

reader.php

```
<?php

class Writer
{

    private $file = "";

    function __construct($theme)
    {
        $this->file = $theme;
        list($list) = explode('.', $this->file, 2);
        $style = $list.".css";


        foreach(file($this->file) as $line) {
            if(strlen($line) < 3){

                echo ("YOU ARE TO DAMM STUPID TO MAKE A CONFIG FILE, IDIOT!");
                return;

         }
            list($name, $type, $label) = explode(":", $line);

            $style_raw = file_get_contents("test.css");

            //$mix = $name.$_GET[$name];
            //print $mix;

            $arr1 = str_split($name);
            $arr2 = str_split($_GET[$name]);

        //  $file = fopen("created/style.css", "w");
            //  fwrite($file, $custom_style);
            //  fclose($file);
    }       

}

}
?>
```

test.theme

```
user:text:Username
color:color:Color
test:password:Password
```

test.css

```
user
color
test
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes I tried to make two arrays but this didnt work...

Comment: Show this code and [edit] your question with it.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Here are some functions that might help you... http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php, and http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php, or http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php.

Comment: With very little research you can come up with something that is fairly simple.

Comment: @chris85 that was what I tried :D

Comment: why is there cursing and name calling in your code?

Comment: @Tom291 user, color, test what a strange .css though. I really don't get your idea. It's still unclear. What do you want to do with $style_raw?

Comment: In style_raw The values should be replaced and wrote into another file. The .css file is not a css  file its just a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to create an array with 2 characters each, which you then split again. So from your string:

```
$str = "1a2b3c";
```

You will create an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1a
    [1] => 2b
    [2] => 3c
)
```

And then to this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => c
        )

)
```

After this you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to use the first character as key and the second as value:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
   //^     ^ replace
   //| search
)
```

Then you can use this array as replacement array in [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), where every key gets replaced with the corresponding value.

Code:

```
<?php

    $str = "1a2b3c";
    $replacement = array_map("str_split", str_split($str, 2));
    $replacement = array_column($replacement, 1, 0);


    file_put_contents("test.css", strtr(file_get_contents("test.css"), $replacement));

?>
```

Comment: But what is when I got words and numbers like colorredbackgroundblue?

Comment: @Tom291 I don't really get what you mean. Please make a little example.

Comment: @Tom291 doesn't matter this just replaces the `a , b , c` so on

Comment: @deW1 but this cuts the string after 2 characters

Comment: @Rizier123 I want to make a stylesheet. The user should be able to edit it. So I got all the informations like: <br />

Comment: there are no numbers in "**colorredbackgroundblue**", nor is there any delimiter.  if the string with the replacement data is anything other than single characters, you'd need to have some way to know where it gets split

Comment: background: red font_color: green but only in this format: backgroundredfontcolorgreen...

Comment: @Tom291 Can't follow you anymore. Please edit your question and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, in my stylesheet theres the following code (for example): background-color: BGCOLOR; now I want to replace the BGCOLOR with the user input

Comment: and I get BGCOLORred. now I want to replace BGCOLOR to red and create a new stylesheet with this

Comment: @Tom291 And how do you want to detect, that you only want to search for `BGCOLOR` and replace it with `red`. And not something like: `BGCOLORre` ; `d` ?

Comment: @Tom291 use keywords for this stuff like `{BGCOLOR}` and replace those with the colors you want.

Comment: I only want to replace it and create a file named style.css: <b>background-color:red;</b>

Comment: @Tom291 How do you want to tell, that you only want to search for `BGCOLOR` and not `BGCOLORre` in `BGCOLORred` ?

Comment: @Tom291 The point deW1 and Rizier123 are talking about is that you need to specify a rule how to parse those settings... like how you determine that this setting belongs to a and another to b.

Comment: This is simple I have got one string : colorbackground... and one: redblue.... and then I mixed it together. Was this wrong?

Comment: @Tom291 it is not clear what part of the text is the property and which is the value... you can have something like  property:value; property:value see this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Comment: @Tom291 It's unclear. Show is what you get as input, what and where you want to replace it.